# How is environmental damage calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it a flat number in a given difficulty and zone, or does it scale with player level and damage (DPS)?

Answer (score 2):

Having just gone back to Normal Act 1 from Nightmare and still having some mobs barely survive a chandelier fall the same as they were on my first play through despite having a good 40 levels more and much better gear, I'm fairly confident at saying it's a fixed damage range per difficulty and effect.